# How can I use a "Select All" checkbox to pass all objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a page where users can select/ unselect employees. I am using `.push` to add these employees to an array, `users`. I have checkboxes for individual users and a checkbox to select / deselect all users. Checking and unchecking individual users works but I'm stuck on tying it in with the "Select All" checkbox.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <label>Select All</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="all" ng-change="addremoveall(all, user.ID)">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="addremoveuser(checked, user.ID)"></td>
        <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
    var users = [];
    $scope.addremoveuser = function (checked, id) {
        if (checked) {
            console.log("user selected", id);
            users.push(id)
            console.log("if test", users);
        }
        else {
            console.log("user unselected", id);
            var index = users.indexOf(id);
            users.splice(index);
            console.log("else test", users);
        }
    };
    $scope.addremoveall = function (all, id) {
            if (all) {
                console.log("all selected", id);
                users.push(id)
                console.log("if test", users);
            }
            else {
                console.log("all unselected", id);
                var index = users.indexOf(id);
                users.splice(index);
                console.log("else test", users);
            }
    };

});
```

Comment: Is the `users` array used for storing the ids in the controller the same as the `users` array used in the `ng-repeat`? That could be an issue.

Comment: @MisterMystery Yes, you are correct. The array would need to be changed to something like `selectedusers`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind each checkbox with the associate user.

Try something like

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label>Select All</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="globalChecked" ng-change="addremoveall()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked" ng-change="addremoveuser(user)"></td>
        <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And

```
$scope.globalChecked = false;

$scope.addremoveuser = function (user) {
    if (user.checked) {
        $scope.users.push(user);
    } else {
        $scope.user.splice(user, 1);
    }
}

$scope.addremoveall = function () {
    for (let i in $scope.users) {
        $scope.users[i].checked = $scope.globalChecked;
    }
}
```